# Solve an Air Conditioning condensate drain problem

Tags: fluid-mechanics

[image]While working from home (a 1968 build retrofitted with A/C) here in FL I've noticed that my A/C drain makes a gurgling sound. I've traced the sound to the condensate drain pipe which appears to be in -ve pressure. As the condensate attempts to drain, the flow is fighting the suction until either the mass of water in the pipe overcomes the suction (and it flows down into the sump pump which periodically empties via the integrated pump) or a water column oscillates in the drain making the gurgling sound. The sound also resonates in the sump cavity adding to the sound intensity. I believe adding a trap in the line may solve the problem thinking when the trap fills with water it will block any air flow and eliminate the noise. My concern is that the trap will simply fill with condensate and instead of flowing down into the sump will back up into the unit. Any help with solving this will be cool. Thanks

Comment: The people at Home Improvement *DIY* SE can probably answer this better. It is more of a practical than theoretical problem. In my experience, a trap located near the same level as where the condensate collects will clog often with sludge. It is better to have it considerably lower, but this is not often possible.

Comment: Thx for the guidance ✌

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to direct you badly, I honestly don't know engineering's ways well enough and shouldn't have sent you here. @ngm01

Answer (score 1):

This is described in most air handler installation docs.  You need a trap with an air space above it.

https://mepacademy.com/ac-condensate-drain-sizing-and-layout/ shows this well.

Answer (score 0):

When adding a trap after the condensate drain you should add a vent after the trap and make the outlet of the trap lower than the inlet.

The vent is there to prevent a siphon from forming when the fan turns off and a bunch of water dumps down the drain.

[image]

The required drop depends on the pressure differential between inside the condenser housing and ambient pressures outside, if you have that number it in inches of water then that is the height needed in inches (do add some margin though).

That way even when the condenser is at lower pressure while the fan is on the column of water at the inlet side of the trap will provide enough pressure to allow the water to reach the outlet side.

Make sure the U is deep enough to keep enough water in the trap so that when the fan kicks on it doesn't break the trap (against the inch of water unit is super helpful here).